# replace color in image of specific portion in c# without selecting that portion

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, colors, replacewith

i want to change color in only one round. not all green color to other color.i have tried with  bmp.SetPixel(j, i, clr); but it replacing all green color

Comment: Do you want to fill an area of the `Bitmap` with one color?

Comment: Give us some code. Show what you already tried. The question is vague enough as it is... what do you mean with "without selecting that portion"?

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Drawing.Graphics.FillRectangle` method:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), 5, 5, 15, 15);
```